# Presentar automaticamente "rutas hijas". Angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0

¿Como puedo hacer que una ruta "child" se ejecute automaticamente? A ver, tengo un archivo de rutas en el que hay:

```
const appRoutes = [
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'proyect-list', component: ProyectList,
        children:[
            {path: 'comp-image-list', component: ImageList, outlet: 'proyectList'},
            {path: 'comp-audio-list', component: AudioList, outlet: 'proyectList'},
            {path: 'comp-video-list', component: VideoList, outlet: 'proyectList'},
            {path: 'comp-web-list', component: WebList, outlet: 'proyectList'}
        ]
    },
    {path: 'singInNow', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'image-detail/:id', component: ImageDetail},
    {path: 'audio-detail/:id', component: AudioDetail},
    {path: 'audio-add', component: AudioAdd},
    {path: 'audio-update/:id', component: AudioUpdate},
    {path: 'video-detail/:id', component: VideoDetail},
```

El archivo no está copiado completo, pero para que os hagais una idea. El caso es que yo voy a "proyect-list" que es una de las rutas principales del sitio. Y dentro de esta página, tengo otro "router-outlet" que contiene esas rutas "child". Lo que yo pretendo es que se presente por ejemplo en el router-outlet de esta el "comp-image-list" sin que yo tenga que dar al enlace que hace que se presente ese componente. ¿Puede llegar a hacerse? He estado leyendo la documentación de Routing de Angular 2, y no he conseguido sacar nada en claro respecto a esto, o no lo he sabido buscar.

El html de la página "proyect-list" es este:

```
<nav class="menuProyect">
        <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'proyectList': ['comp-image-list'] } }]" class="menuProyectLink">Imagen</a>
        <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'proyectList': ['comp-audio-list'] } }]" class="menuProyectLink">Audio</a>
        <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'proyectList': ['comp-video-list'] } }]" class="menuProyectLink">Video</a>
        <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'proyectList': ['comp-web-list'] } }]" class="menuProyectLink">Web</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet name="proyectList"></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes de añadir en el array de rutas **children** la ruta por defecto:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'comp-image-list', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'comp-image-list', component: ImageList }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias dddenis. Era evidente como había que hacerlo, pero no me ha dado el coco para haberme dado cuenta de ello. Muchas gracias por la sencillez y rapidez a la hora de responder. Funciona correctamente de la forma que me has comentado. Gracias.

Comment: Me alegro @H.Díaz , no te preocupes, el tema de las rutas de Angular la verdad no están muy claras en mi opinión.